# Kann man "halten" anstatt des "abhalten" in diesem Kontext benutzen?

Tags: meaning, verb-usage

Kann man in diesem Satz (aus einem [Artikel in der Welt](https://%20https://www.welt.de/politik/ausland/plus243239559/Ukraine-Eine-neue-Front-So-gefaehrlich-ist-die-russisch-belarussische-Achse.html))

> "Putin und Lukaschenko lassen in Belarus gemeinsame Militärmanöver
> abhalten."

das Verb durch "halten" ersetzen?

Was sind die Unterschiede in der Bedeutung zwischen halten und abhalten?

Comment: Ich versteh die Frage nicht ganz. Was soll das Verb von "halten" denn sein? Was möchtest Du ersetzt sehen? Der Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen 'halten' und dem hier genutzten 'abhalten' ist in der Antwort von guidot erklärt und damit klar, dass sie nicht synonym sind.

Comment: @John Lamb ich habe die Formulierung der Frage überarbeitet. Ich hoffe das entspricht dem, was du ausdrücken wolltest. Du kannst sie natürlich jederzeit wieder editieren, falls das nicht der Fall sein sollte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Abhalten* wird hier in der Bedeutung 4, "eine Zusammenkunft veranstalten, stattfinden lassen" vgl. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/abhalten) verwendet. Interessant ist, dass *Manöver* sogar im Abschnitt *Typische Verbindungen* mit hoher Häufigkeit dargestellt ist.

Keine der vielen Bedeutungen von [halten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/halten) geht in diese Richtung, deswegen würde ich von einem Ersetzen zumindest abraten, man kann *halten* sogar als falsch betrachten.. Da ein treffenderes Verb existiert, ist es auch besserer Stil.

Comment: "abraten" ist vielleicht ein bißchen schwach - "Putin läßt Manöver halten" transportiert was ganz andres (nämlich ehen "anhalten" statt "abhalten".

Comment: Hier ist vorsicht geboten. Politischer sowie Militärjargon kann je nach Rang absurd archaisch sein. Das dürfte zwar außer Frage stehen, da die Frage hypothetisch zu sein scheint.